# Oracle PLSQL XML Canonicalization i.e. C14N generation

Tags: xml, plsql

Do you know if it is possible via Oracle PLSQL to produce XML that is considered canonicalised (i.e. XML http://mcaf.ee/ufs3z) ?

I see Oracle have a Java API C14NTransform I think this is for private use only
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/apirefs.1111/e10680/oracle/security/xmlsec/transform/C14NTransform.html

Anyone have experience with this ?

Darragh.

Answer (score 0):

let oracle xml functionality do the work for you ...
assuming you define a variable `l_xml_data` of datatype `clob` to hold your non-canonicalized xml:

```
  WITH xdata AS
     (
        SELECT xmltype ( l_xml_data )   xml
          from dual
     )
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE ( CONTENT extract(xml, '/rootelement') )  x
  FROM xdata
     ;
```

refer to the follwing 2 fiddles for illustration. the only difference is the source of the xml which is a simple demo table.

be sure to choose 'markdown output' from the dropdown menu of the run sql button.

- [non-canonicalized](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b020/4/0)
- [canonicalized](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b020/3/0)

i havenn't exhaustively tested the result for compliance with the c14n-standard. however, it should get you started.

the use of this scheme in plsql code has been tested, however.

regards.